# Can't assign role to user from Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

All of a certain I'm facing an issue. On my application IdentityRole and IdentityUser not working in the Repository but everything works fine on the controller method. Here is my code -

> from controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssignRole(List<UserRoleViewModel> model, string roleId)
{
    ViewBag.roleId = roleId;
    //_accounts.AssignRole(model, roleId);

    IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

    for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model[i].UserId);

        IdentityResult result;

        if (model[i].IsSelected && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)))
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        }
        else if (!model[i].IsSelected && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
        {
            result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (i < (model.Count - 1))
                continue;
            else
                return RedirectToAction("UsersInRole", new { id = roleId });
        }
    }

    //return _response;

    return RedirectToAction("UsersInRole", new { id = roleId });
}
```

> From Repository

```
public async Task<Response> AssignRole(List<UserRoleViewModel> model, string roleId)
{
    Response _response = new();
    _response.flag = 0;

    IdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

    for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model[i].UserId);

        IdentityResult result;

        if (model[i].IsSelected && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)))
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        }
        else if (!model[i].IsSelected && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
        {
            result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (i < (model.Count - 1))
                continue;
            else
                return _response;
        }
    }

    return _response;
}
```

If any further information is needed please comment below I'm looking forward for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Details please. Is there any runtime error? Something unexpected? Code not compiling? etc.

Comment: I mean can't assign a role to users. There's no runtime error. It just returns some point to action.

Comment: It is concerning that you have almost identical code running in a controller action method and a repository method. Remember the DRY principle Don't Repeat Yourself.

Anyway... the easiest way to find out why it's returning without the result you expected is to set a breakpoint at the beginning of each method and step through the code one line at a time until you see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I tried with brake point but no matter how hard I try results are the same. The return point is random. This means it does not return from the same point each time.

Comment: And I don't use a repository and controller at the same time. I just write the code on this post.